# Вырезать слово или слова из строки после *паттерн*

Tags: java

К примеру у меня есть строка

`CurrentlyPlaying(context=Context(type=PLAYLIST, href=https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/29GSd1GDp2VSxhUcz0pyzA, externalUrls=ExternalUrl(externalUrls={spotify=https://open.spotify.com/playlist/29GSd1GDp2VSxhUcz0pyzA}), uri=spotify:playlist:29GSd1GDp2VSxhUcz0pyzA), timestamp=1648062889952, progress_ms=170258, is_playing=true, item=Track(name=Rainbow In The Dark, artists=[ArtistSimplified(name=Dio)`

Как из неё вырезать слово после `artists=[ArtistSimplified(name=`
Чтобы получилось `Dio`?

Я пробовал что-то такое

```java
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("artists=[ArtistSimplified(name=");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(currentlyPlaying.toString());
    while (m.find()){
        i++;
    }
    // здесь substring по индексу i
```

но не получается и выдает 4 почему-то..

Comment: вы сейчас явно пытаетесь прикрутить костыль, который точно прикручивать не надо)) подскажите для начала, откуда берется эта строка?

Comment: Это строка из Spotify API. Там есть возможность только вырезать название, но не автора. Пытаюсь автора тоже получить

Comment: Spotify API в соответсвтвии с официальной документацией возвращает данные в формате json: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, в заданном шаблоне используются символы `(` и `[`, которые нужно экранировать при помощи символа `'\'`.  Во-вторых, не задана группа, которая определяла бы местонахождение имени исполнителя.

Следует изменить шаблон и вывод обнаруженного имени:

```java
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("artists=\\[ArtistSimplified\\(name=([^)]*)\\)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(currentlyPlaying.toString());
while (m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group(1)); // -> Dio
}
```

Также можно сразу искать название трека с использованием именованных групп `(?<название_группы>шаблон)`:

```java
// используются именованные группы
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Track\\(name=(?<track>[^,)]*), artists=\\[ArtistSimplified\\(name=(?<artist>[^)]*)\\)");

Matcher m = p.matcher(currentlyPlaying.toString());

while (m.find()) {
    System.out.printf("'%s' by %s%n", m.group("track"), m.group("artist"));
}
// -> 'Rainbow In The Dark' by Dio
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, я в regex вообще не разбираюсь. Заменил правда "Track\\(name=(?<track>[^,)]*), artists=\\[ArtistSimplified\\(name=(?<artist>[^)]*)\\)" на  "Track\\(name=(?<track>[^,)]*), artists=\\[ArtistSimplified\\(name=(?<artist>[^)]*)\\," и теперь все работает

Comment: Я исходил из представленного образца текста, потому и ограничил имя исполнителя  скобкой.  В вашем примере похоже появилась некая запятая.  Эти символы можно объединить при помощи набора символов `[,)]`, что по сути более краткий  аналог ИЛИ `(\\,|\\))`.

Comment: Но если данные возвращаются в формате JSON, то лучше сериализовать ответ как Java объект и работать с его полями/свойствами.

Comment: По сути вид (name=Dio, *ссылка на исполнителя*), при помощи замены ')' на ',' все заработало. По поводу JSON, он мне толком не нужен, тем более я понятия не имею как это реализовать т.к совсем новичек. Ещё раз спасибо!